(Solved) CentOS Web Panel - Apache start fails due to missing SSL certificate
The long story: Due to some problem at the vendor's end, my VPS has been migrated to a new IP address. Now, the Apache server is refusing to start. When I try to click Start, I get the error message
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Upon typing "systemctl status httpd.service" in the terminal, I get the following result
● httpd.service - Web server Apache
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-08-23 11:02:49 IST; 5min ago
  Process: 2484 ExecStart=/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Aug 23 11:02:48 ark.mediagenies.com systemd[1]: Starting Web server Apache...
Aug 23 11:02:49 ark.mediagenies.com apachectl[2484]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 17 of /usr/local/apache/conf.d/vhosts/ark.mediagenies.com.ssl.conf:
Aug 23 11:02:49 ark.mediagenies.com apachectl[2484]: SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/pki/tls/certs/ark.mediagenies.com.cert' does not exist or is empty
Aug 23 11:02:49 ark.mediagenies.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 23 11:02:49 ark.mediagenies.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Web server Apache.
Aug 23 11:02:49 ark.mediagenies.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Aug 23 11:02:49 ark.mediagenies.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.

So, I can see that it has to do with a missing SSL certificate on the host (which in my case is 'ark.mediagenies.com'). Now, when I go to the SSL Certificates page and try to renew the SSL Certificate I get the following error
"DNS Redirection problem for ark.mediagenies.com with www and without it"

What needs to be done here? Do I need to add an A record to the DNS zone, or something? Not sure at all. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Option 1 - disable the SSL website and then your immediate Apache configuration issue is solved and the web server will start. - Option 2 : make a dummy / place holder/ self-signed  certificate  (for example with openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ark.mediagenies.com.key -nodes -x509 -days 365 -out ark.mediagenies.com.cert ) and use that temporarily in your web server config while you get sorted with a proper certificate.  -/- As to why you get the error that you're getting: you don't provide enough information for that

I am not sure why it happened, to be honest. I think my server vendor, in migrating the VPS to another IP address, made some error. That's all I can say.
However, Option 1 worked. Thanks for the input!

I solved this by removing the subdomain associated with my host, after which Apache started right up. I was then able to install autossl without any issues.
